# Access data of additional settings of region on Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, region

You can change measurement system in:

> Windows settings => Time & Language => Additional date, time & regional settings => change date, time, or number formats => Additional settings => Measurement system

When you use `RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric` in C#, this data isn't related to what you have chosen in settings.

How to access from C# code currently chosen Measurement system?

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that RegionInfo.IsMetric is (staticaly) related to region, not to your custom settings.

Comment: It's not supposed to. The class's [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.regioninfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) says : `Unlike the CultureInfo class, the RegionInfo class does not represent user preferences and does not depend on the user's language or culture.` This class contains the region information provided by the OS

Comment: Well, if it does not represent user preferences that's exactly why I mustn't use it. I need c# to know my preferences set in settings, not the static info binded to region.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's the `RegionInfo` class in general and not specifically `RegionInfo.CurrentRegion` which represents the current settings. The [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.regioninfo.currentregion?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) says: *The value of this property is based on the culture selected through the regional and language options portion of Control Panel.*

Comment: @phuclv that's a documentation bug then. The class Remarks shouldn't contradict the property docs or the actual behavior

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found that solution (C#):
`Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International", "iMeasure", 0)`

It's Windows registry that stores info about chosen measurement system (not the one bound to region).

Answer (score 0):

`RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric` should work, as documented by MS:

> **The value of this property is based on the culture selected through the regional and language options portion of Control Panel.** However, that information can change during the life of the [AppDomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?view=net-6.0). The [RegionInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.regioninfo?view=net-6.0) class does not automatically detect changes in the system settings, but the [CurrentRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.regioninfo.currentregion?view=net-6.0) property is updated when you call the [ClearCachedData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clearcacheddata?view=net-6.0) method.
>
> **[RegionInfo.CurrentRegion Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.regioninfo.currentregion?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Globalization_RegionInfo_CurrentRegion)**

I've tested on .NET Core 6.0, `Console.WriteLine(RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric);` prints out the correct value every time I change the unit in Control Panel. You just need to relaunch the app after changing the regional options, or call `ClearCachedData()`

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind, this below single line code doesn't work most of the time while manually changing units between Metric/U.S, **SO DO NOT USE THIS BELOW LINE**

```
System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric;
```

What @salverio wrote works perfectly.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

public static bool IsMetric(string KeyPath,
                            string KeyName)
{
    try
    {
        string input;
        input = ReadRegistry(KeyPath, KeyName);

        if (input == "0")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (input == "1")
        {
            return false;
        }

        return System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric;
    }
}


public static string ReadRegistry(string path,
                                    string name)
{
    try
    {
        string output = "";

        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(path))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                object o = key.GetValue(name);
                if (o != null)
                {
                    output = o as string;
                }
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Just simply call the function IsMetric(registry key path, registry key name)

Where,

```
KeyPath = @"Control Panel\International";
KeyName = "iMeasure";
```

Comment: `System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric` works: [The value of this property is based on the culture selected through the regional and language options portion of Control Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.regioninfo.currentregion?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks). If you change the settings during run time you'll have to call `ClearCachedData()` manually to reload the settings